# Can I use a list of packages in a variable in a bash script?

Tags: apt, bash, scripts, 19.10

I'm trying to make a bash script for bring a new OS up where I want it.

For some reason, I cannot get a simple variable list of packages to apt-get install

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST_OF_PACKAGES="docker smartmontools"
apt-get -y install $LIST_OF_PACKAGES
```

I've tried several variations, but they all fail. Just keep saying "unable to locate package"

But when I do

```
apt-cache search docker
```

I'll find the package.

Also, the other package was not installed even though there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my issue was making this file on a Windows machine, and moving it over to Linux without first converting it!

Worked as expected after installing dos2unix and using it to convert my .sh file!

Comment: Note that this approach only works because package names don't contain whitespace, and you didn't quote the list variable. A more general approach to the question *"Can I use a list of xxx in a variable in a bash script?"* would be to use an array: `list_of_xxx=(item1 "item 2" item3)` then `some_command "${list_of_xxx[@]}"`